# Dual boot to Single boot | Windows/Ubuntu on SSD/External HDD to Ubuntu on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows, ssd, 22.04

A while ago, I installed Ubuntu on my External HDD, while Windows stayed on my laptop's SSD. Now, I wish to change it to just be Ubuntu on SSD.

What is the best way to achieve this? Move the current Ubuntu OS from the HDD to SSD, overwriting Windows, or installing Ubuntu onto Windows and removing the previous Ubuntu OS (after moving everything)?

I do not have that much experience with tools like GParted, and while *to me, currently,* it does not *seem* to be very difficult, the guides I've found only appear to show one type of drive with both OSes installed.

Answer (score 2):

Technically by far the easiest way is to reinstall Ubuntu from the live medium on the internal SSD, selecting the option "Use entire disk" in the installer. Other options are much more technical and require manual interventions in the terminal.